# simple mysqli query dont work

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I try to learn mysql an have a problem with a sql query.

i made a database connection with mysqli
the php script create a table code_scanned in database.

Creating the Table works very good!
But my second query to fill the table wont work :(

If i paste the query manually to phpadmin it works.

But not in my php script.

Can please anyone have a look on my code, what i do wrong.

```
$servername = "xxxxxxx";
$username = "xxxxxx";
$password = "xxxxxx";
$dbname = "xxxxxx";



// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

// sql to create table
$sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS code_scanned (
id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
produkt VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
code VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
)";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "code_scanned erstellt";
} else {
    echo "Fehler" . $conn->error;
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO code_scanned (produkt, code) VALUES ('gates', 'Microsoft')";


$conn->close();
```

Comment: you never executed the insert

Comment: You should also be testing the result of `$conn->query($sql)` for FALSE to spot errors and not TRUE to see if it was successful, as a successful call returns a `mysqli_result` object and not TRUE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exexute the insert query :

And correct The code:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO code_scanned (produkt, code) VALUES ('gates', 'Microsoft')";
$result= mysqli_query($conn,$sql);    
if($result)
{
echo "Insert sucessfully";
} 
else
{
 echo("Sorry:".mysqli_errno($conn));
}

$conn->close();
```

Comment: Hi Thank you for the fast replay. Now its working. How can i display mysql error as text. If i have a error i see only error code.1045 for example

Comment: change mysqli_errno($conn) to mysql_error($conn)

Answer (score 0):

You are not running the second query. Put this below the line that has `$sql = "INSERT...."`

```
$conn->query($sql);
```

Comment: Thank you now its working :). But i don´t understand why my first query is executed. Its the same syntacx without $conn->query

Comment: `if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {` This line is executing the first query ;).